# Do deposits of Adamantium exist?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

In-universe, if someone is willing to make a sword out of Adamantium (for example to fight Wolverine), are there places where they could find it?

Is this a metal that one can mine or purchase? And if yes, where would one find these deposits?

Comment: Are you asking in-universe?

Comment: Yes I'm asking in universe

Comment: Are you asking if Adamantium deposits exist and where you'd find those deposits?

Comment: Yes this is what I was want to know

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you can find some adamantium, you will not be able to fight Wolverine. He's too fast and strong, and he heals much faster than you. Sorry about that. I'd suggest you aim for easier opponents, like Ronda Rousey and Chris Kyle. ;)

Comment: Don't worry we have some DNA samples of his and more likely to make a clone with enhanced abilities soon

Comment: As written, your comments conflict with the question. *You* can't find adamantium because *you* aren't a character in the X-Men films.

Comment: Perhaps the question could be changed to "where is adamantium ore found in the Marvel universe."

Comment: @RogueJedi, is it the same universe?

Comment: @TimSparrow The other question is about the 616 Marvel comic universe. I suppose this one could be edited to only be about the X-Men film series, and therefore cease to be a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Marvel website entry](http://marvel.com/universe/Adamantium) Adamantium does not occur naturally, but is instead produced by combining chemical resins. The details of the procedure are a closely guarded secret, although there is canonical precedent for leaks.

So, **no** on there being deposits and **only very rarely, expensively & illegally** on it being for sale anywhere, much in the same way you can't buy a nuclear warhead easily.

Comment: Also, assuming a Wolverine with his full set of regenerative properties, what good is a sword going to do?

Comment: A sword did a decent amount in the movie "the wolverine" - but who takes those seriously?